# check to see if fields are empy, if not, do calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using the following if-structure to check wether or not the cells have a valid value in them

```
als(([Gemeten demping 1]="") of ([Gemeten demping 2]="");"";([Gemeten demping 1]+[Gemeten demping 2])/2)
```

als = IF

of = OR

What this should do is; check if "gemeten demping1" or "gemeten demping2" fields are empty, if they are not empty, calculate the average value

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use OR like that. OR is an operator that takes 2 parameters. So instead of the way you are using it right now, you have to do

```
OR([Gemeten demping 1]="", [Gemeten demping 2]="")
```

inside of your if statement.

Comment: Haha yes! after some more looking around I found this answer too! thanks alot!